# Identify if user has watched a video

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, video, youtube

I am developing an application that requires a user to view a set of videos.

How can I identify if the user has watched a particular video(complete and incomplete)?

Comment: How are the videos being provided to the user?

Comment: Do you mean YouTube video, HTML5 video or what?

Comment: Unless you ping the server for every X seconds of video watched, how would you be able to reliably tell between someone having watched the entire video, and someone who just skipped to the end?

Comment: The only way you know that a human being has actually watched a video is to quiz them on its contents. Sites that do particular kinds of education programs, like for example legal requirements things for an employee community, generally include questions in the quiz that are not so much about the subject matter but instead about the detailed content of the video (like, "What color car did Mary get into in the second scene?").

Comment: Do you have a members system? If not > Depends what you are using to play the video. But you should create a session when the user enters the page, then when the video is completed try to find a callback which adds video watched to the session. However I dno if you can stop people from fast forwarding etc. Check youtubes API for callbacks.

Comment: Also remember that you, at most, can determine that the video was *played.* There is no way to determine if the human sat there and *watched it*. The person may have hidden the video's window behind another window and muted the sound. Or simply left the computer to have a coffee break.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed the video on a page on your website, so you can register it that way.

You could also put a URL at the end of the video that they must follow to register they've seen the video.

I *hope* that the answer is "you can't" if you're talking about having watched it directly from YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php's session variables, and put each video on a different webpage. Then when one video ends it redirects to another webpage and adds a value to that session. Before each page is loaded the session checks to see if the user should be on that webpage like so:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['videos']=="whatever value"){ //check to see if the session equals what value it should
$_SESSION['videos'] = 'whatever value2'; //update the value for next webpage
}
else { //if session variable doesn't equal what it should, redirect to homepage
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

and to figure out when the video ends, just set a timer to the exact length of the video. I think you can figure that out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Ah youtube videos. I made a YouTube Client that could do exactly what your referring to. It was a Client side URL sniffer that checked various urls for the presence of a youtube video ID. It could detect when a video was watched embedded in a site and many other places where the video could be watched.

Unfortunately, Firefox has changed their JS Engine to disallow URL sniffers, so finding if youtube videos have been watched via javascript is now out of the question. Your last option might be to authenticate the user under their youtube account and check the History. Good Luck!